# Change a dynamic variable name with rxSetVarInfo

Tags: microsoft-r

Trying to change a variable name of an XDF with rxSetVarInfo.

I want to merge several data sets with common var names.  (I know rxMerge can/will append to filenames where needed.  I want to have more control than that.)

This works:

```
outLetter<- "A"
exp <- list(pct.A = list(newName = paste0("X.pct.",outLetter)))
rxSetVarInfo(varInfo = exp, data = tempXDFFile)
```

That's where I know the original column name, `pct.A`. What if that's dynamic?  What if this is in a function that gets called several times with different `outLetter`'s.  (The "A" isn't hardcoded.)
This does not work:

```
function(outLetter){
  exp <- list(paste0("pct.",outLetter) = list(newName = paste0("X.pct.",outLetter)))
  rxSetVarInfo(varInfo = exp, data = tempXDFFile)
}
```

Nor does:

```
exp <- parse(text = exp)
rxSetVarInfo(varInfo = exp, data = tempXDFFile)
```

Yes, I can hardcode all the permutations.  Trying to find a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
dynamicName <- function(outLetter){
  exp <- vector(mode="list", length=1)
  names(exp) <- paste0("pct.",outLetter)
  exp[[paste0("pct.",outLetter)]] = list(newName = paste0("X.pct.",outLetter))
  rxSetVarInfo(varInfo = exp, data = tempXDFFile)
}
```

Before the call to rxSetVarInfo(), "exp" contains:

```
$pct.A
$pct.A$newName
[1] "X.pct.A"
```

Running your "this works" case, I see:

```
> outLetter<- "A"
> exp <- list(pct.A = list(newName = paste0("X.pct.",outLetter)))
>
> exp
$pct.A
$pct.A$newName
[1] "X.pct.A"
```

Hope this helps!

Note, please make sure that your dynamic naming function has access to the variable "tempXDFFile", you may want to consider passing it as a parameter, like:

```
dynamicName <- function(outLetter, data){
  exp <- vector(mode="list", length=1)
  names(exp) <- paste0("pct.",outLetter)
  exp[[paste0("pct.",outLetter)]] = list(newName = paste0("X.pct.",outLetter))
  rxSetVarInfo(varInfo = exp, data = data)
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you.