# rxDataStep "transform" argument using quasi-quotation

Tags: r, microsoft-r, quasiquotes

I am trying to use the quasi-quotation syntax (`quo`, `exprs`, `!!`, etc.) as well as the `foreach` function to create several new variables by means of a named list of expressions to be evaluated inside the `rxDataStep` function, specifically, the `transforms` argument. I am getting the following error:

```
Error in rxLinkTransformComponents(transforms = transforms, transformFunc = transformFunc,  : 'transforms' must be of the form list(...)
```

I have a dataset which includes a number of variables with I need to log-transform in order to perform further analyses. I have been using the `rx` functions from the "RevoScaleR" package for roughly three years and totally missed the "tidyverse"/pipeline method of data transformation techniques. I do occasionally dabble with these tools but prefer to stick with the aforementioned `rx` functions giving my relative familiarity and the fact that they have served me very well thus far.

---

As a MWE:

Required libraries:

```
library(foreach)
library(rlang)
```

Creating variables which need to be log-transformed.

```
vars <- foreach(i = 10:20, .combine = "cbind") %do% rnorm(10, i)
```

Dataframe with identifier and above variables.

```
data_in <- data.frame(id = 1:10, vars)
```

Object which creates the expressions of the log-transformed variables; this creates a named list.

```
log_vars <- foreach(i = names(data_in[-1]), .final = function(x) set_names(x, paste0(names(data_in[-1]), "_log"))) %do%
expr(log10(!!sym(i)))
```

Now attempting to add the variables to the existing dataframe.

```
data_out <- rxDataStep(inData = data_in, transforms = log_vars, transformObjects = list(log_vars = log_vars))
```

The resulting error is the following:

```
Error in rxLinkTransformComponents(transforms = transforms, transformFunc = transformFunc,  :  'transforms' must be of the form list(...)
```

I simply cannot understand the error given that `log_vars` is defined as a named list. One can check this with `str` and `typeof`.

I have tried a slightly different way of defining the new variables:

```
log_vars <- unlist(foreach(i = names(data_in[-1]), j = paste0(names(data_in[-1]), "_log")) %do%
exprs(!!j := log10(!!sym(i))))
```

I have to use `unlist` given that `exprs` delivers a list as output already. Either way, I get the same error as before.

Naturally, I expect to have 10 new variables named `result.1_log, result.2_log`, etc. inserted into the dataframe. Instead, I receive the above error and the new dataframe is not created.

---

I suspected that the `rx` functions do not like working with the quasi-quotation syntax, however, I have used it before when having to identify subjects with NA values of certain variables. This was done using the `rowSelection` argument of `rxDataStep`. I do realise that `rowSelection` requires a single, logical expression while `transforms` requires a named list of expressions.

Any help would be much appreciated since this type of data transformation will keep up again in my analyses. I do suspect that I simply do not understand the inner workings of the quasi-quotation syntax or perhaps how lists work in general but, hopefully there is a simple fix.

I am using Microsoft R Open 3.4.3.

---

My session info is the following:

`R Services Information:
    Local R: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ML Server\R_SERVER\
    Version: 1.3.40517.1016
    Operating System: Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134 
    CPU Count: 4
    Physical Memory: 12169 MB, 6810 MB free
    Virtual Memory: 14025 MB, 7984 MB free
    Video controller[1]: Intel(R) HD Graphics 620
    GPU[1]: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
    Video memory[1]: 1024 MB
    Connected users: 1`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do as I think you've made things too complicated.
If all you want to do is take the log of each # in each data point, then I show two approaches below.

1. Approach #1 is static, you know the fixed # of columns and hard code it.  It's a bit faster for rxDataStep to run in this approach.
2. Approach #2 is a bit more dynamic, taking advantage of a transformFunc.  transformFunc works in chunks, so it can be used safely in a clustered fashion.  rxDataStep knows how to integrate the chunks together.  But there will be a bit of a performance hit for it.
3. You might have been trying to find a hybrid approach - dynamically build the list for the transforms parameter in the rxDataStep.  I haven't found a way to get that to work.  Here's a similar question for doing it in rxSetVarInfo ([Change a dynamic variable name with rxSetVarInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668701/change-a-dynamic-variable-name-with-rxsetvarinfo)) but using that approach hasn't yielded success for me yet.

Let me know if I've completely missed the mark!

```
library(foreach)
library(rlang)

startSize <- 10
endSize <- 20
vars <- foreach(i = startSize:endSize, .combine = "cbind") %do% rnorm(10, i)

data_in <- data.frame(vars)
tempInput <- tempfile(fileext = ".xdf")
tempOutput <- tempfile(fileext = ".xdf")

rxImport(inData = data_in, outFile = tempInput, overwrite = T)
rxGetInfo(tempInput, getVarInfo = T)

### Approach #1
print("Approach #1")

rxDataStep(inData = tempInput, outFile = tempOutput, overwrite = T,
       transforms = list(
         log_R1 = log10(result.1),
         log_R2 = log10(result.2),
         log_R3 = log10(result.3),
         log_R4 = log10(result.4),
         log_R5 = log10(result.5),
         log_R6 = log10(result.6),
         log_R7 = log10(result.7),
         log_R8 = log10(result.8),
         log_R9 = log10(result.9),
         log_R10 = log10(result.10),
         log_R11 = log10(result.11)))

rxGetInfo(tempOutput, getVarInfo = T)

### Approach #2
print("Approach #2")

logxform <- function(dataList) {
  numRowsInChunk <- length(dataList$result.1)

  for (j in 1:columnDepth) { 
    dataList[[paste0("log_R",j)]] <- rep(0, times=numRowsInChunk)
    for (i in 1:numRowsInChunk) {
     dataList[[paste0("log_R",j)]][i] <- log10(dataList[[paste0("result.",j)]][i])
    }
  }
  return(dataList)
}
rxDataStep(inData = tempInput, outFile = tempOutput, overwrite = T,
           transformObjects = list(columnDepth = endSize - startSize + 1), 
           transformFunc = logxform)

rxGetInfo(tempOutput, getVarInfo = T)
```